# Animate switching grid sizing

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, jss

I have a project with React and Material UI.

I need some guidance on how to animate a grid item size change. The item is by default sm={3}, when the user hovers the item, this changes to sm={6}.

Here is my code:

```
<Grid
                        item
                        xs={this.state.hoverItem ? 6 : 3}
                        spacing={24}
                        onMouseEnter={this.handleItemHover}
                        onMouseLeave={this.handleItemHoverLeave}
                    >
                        <Paper
                            elevation={this.state.hoverItem ? 5 : 1}
                            className={classNames(
                                classes.card,
                                this.state.hoverItem && classes.cardHover
                            )}
                            >
</Paper>
</Grid>
```

And this is how I am doing my JSS:

```
card: {
    ...theme.mixins.gutters(),
    paddingTop: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
    paddingBottom: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
    transition: theme.transitions.create("width", {
        easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
        duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen
    })
},
cardHover: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create("width", {
        easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
        duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen
    })
},
```

I thought this should animate it. However, the transitions are not doing anything.

Comment: There is no sufficient code to determinate the problem from what you posted. Can you add more code or put link to codebox or jsbin or something similar_

Answer (score 0):

Hi it was really an interesting problem of the day, I have tried to implement with simple transitions on hover. You can see here on codesandbox :

[Animate Switching Grid Size](https://codesandbox.io/s/pj2l4jmv6j)

PS I have added your transition property as comment without giving **width** It worked great. You can report issue on [`Material-UI`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues) this is the right time.

Please let me know if you the issue still persists.